# How to create an entity object in Spring Boot when the entire table is the key?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity

I'm creating an entity object that I will use to query a database with. However, I'm not sure how to build it since all of the columns are the key for the table. Typically I'd create an Entity object with the parameters that aren't the key and make a nested object within that one as the key. That entity object key would hold the values needed to build the key. But, in this case, all 5 values of the table are used for the key.

This is what I have currently, but I know that it's wrong.

Would I just have to make an @EmbeddedId key object within this one and push all of the values to that while practically leaving this base entity object empty? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "<insert>", schema="<insert>")
public class Market {

        @Id
        @Column(name="MKT_ID")
        private String marketId;

        @Column(name="DLR_CD")
        private String dealerCd;

        @Column(name="SER_NO_PFX")
        private String serialNoPrefix;

        @Column(name="SER_NO_BDY")
        private String serialNoBody;

        @Column(name="USER_ID")
        private String userId;
}
```

Comment: Is MKT_ID unique?

Comment: The table is not completely normalized no. That's why I'd need all 5 of the values as a composite key of sorts. I wish it was unique, because then what I have here would probably work.